# Angular2 material designe

Tags: angular2, material-design

Я изучаю angular2 + material design,  и хочу   создать  selectbox с помощью материал. Я использую  [этот](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-select) модуль . Мой  код 
   `<md-select>
     <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
     <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
     <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
     <md-option value="4">4</md-option>
  </md-select>`
 Но получаю 
[image: селдующую ошибку]

Answer (score 1):

В основной ветке material2 пока нет md-select https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/118

> If you guys really need an "md-select" right now, check out this one (while the material2 gets done)
>
> https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ng2-material-select